# How can you mention a policy requiring customers to have something to eat if they drink alcohol in a restaurant?

Tags: traducción

I work at a restaurant and our policy requires our customers to have something to eat if they drink alcohol.

I was wondering how I could explain this in Spanish.

Comment: How doy you say in English? ¿Cómo lo dice en inglés?

Comment: Hello, Megan, and welcome to the site! What have you tried so far? If you know what to say in your native language, you could try to translate it into Spanish and show us what you've come up with. If you don't know a word of Spanish you could try some automatic services such as Google Translate. Note that we're not a translation service, we're here to answer questions for people who wants to learn Spanish. You can [edit] your question and provide an attempt of translation and we'll gladly help you polish it.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to convey a message similar to the idea you have expressed in English, you could say something like:

- *Por política de la casa, no se puede beber alcohol sin ordenar algo para comer. ¿Gustaría ordenar algo?* (Our policy dictates that customers can't drink alcohol without ordering something to eat. Would you like to order something?)

Answer (score 1):

In case you're a beginning Spanish speaker, I'll make a very simple suggestion.  You might want to keep in a pocket of your apron, written on an index card.  If you forget, you can refer to it, or show it to the customer.

> No se vende alcohol sin comida.

*Alcohol* can be a little challenging to pronounce for a beginner, so if they're trying to order wine or beer, I'd substitute the specific name in place of *alcohol*.  (*vino / cerveza*)

Back-translating, the simple sentence means:

> Alcohol is not served [here] without food.